# ObservableArray in template not applying visible binding after creation

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

For whatever reason, I cannot get knockout to trigger an update on visible whenever the `GroupType` select list changes. I have a cut-down example below:

```
<script id="process" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <select data-bind="value: GroupType">
        <option value="0">example 0</option>
        <option value="1">example 1</option>
        <option value="2">example 2</option>
        <option value="3">example 3</option>
    </select>
    <select data-bind="value: Group, visible: GroupType() == '2'">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Group, visible: GroupType() != '2'"/>
</script>

<div data-bind="template { name: 'process', foreach: Processes }"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        Processes: ko.observableArray([
            { GroupType: ko.observable("1"), Group: ko.observable("Blah") },
            { GroupType: ko.observable("2"), Group: ko.observable("1") }
        ])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

**EDIT 1:** I have included the changes suggested below, but instead of allowing the two items to switch, it just shows the last one regardless of the selected `GroupType`

**EDIT 2:** I have made a jsFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/2jjgH/

**EDIT 3 (Final):** Edit has been made above to reflect answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observableArrays` only notify on changes to the array itself (add items, remove items, replace the entire array).  They do not track the individual properties.  You would need to make `GroupType` and `Group` `observables` to have the UI updated in your scenario.

Comment: I just tried that. I will update the code above to reflect your response, but instead of showing the appropriate input format initially, it will always show the latter.

Comment: When you switch to GroupType being an observable, then you need to update your logic to look like `data-bind="value: Group, visible: GroupType() == '2'"`